# StackCreate ValidationError: Condition token can only be used in Conditions block

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I am trying to apply my cloudformation template and I am getting the following cryptic error:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationError)
>   when calling the CreateStack operation: Template error: Condition
>   token can only be used in Conditions block

The stack trace is

```
  File "/Users/user/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

The code looks like

```
cf_client = session.client('cloudformation')
cf_client.create_stack(
        StackName=stack_name,
        TemplateBody=template_body,
        Parameters=aws_parameters,
        TimeoutInMinutes=10,
        OnFailure='DELETE',
        Tags=aws_tags,
        Capabilities=['CAPABILITY_IAM'],
    )
```

The cloudformation template is massive and not appropriate to paste here. It stands up an application with service discovery, app mesh, fargate, etc.

What is this `Condition` they're referring to and what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error is rather cryptic and unhelpful but in my case, it was a typo in my ECS task definition.

My container has a depends on relationship and I had misconstructed the

```
      DependsOn:
      - ContainerName: envoy
      - Condition: HEALTHY
```

Depends on is a list of maps so there should not be a `-` in front of `Condition`.

This corrects my problem:

```
      DependsOn:
      - ContainerName: envoy
        Condition: HEALTHY
```